# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute

Tags: django

If I make a context processor like this:

```
def add_external(request):
    context = {"stext":"this is the info"}
    return context
```

and add this to the settings:

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        'website.context_processor.add_external',
    ],
```

I can access the variable in the template via `{{stext}}`. When I now jump from a link in this template into another view in the same app shouldn't I be able to access this variable as:

```
request.stext
```

Instead I get this error:

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'stext'
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: No, context processors don't add attributes to the request object, and they certainly don't make data available in a completely different request. Why do you think this should work?

Comment: You are right, I was trying to do something that is technically completely impossible. I resolved it by using session middleware (although the code only looks different in same detail -request.session instead of request -, there is a lot of stuff going on in the background).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implemented context processor, which data are available only inside of templates, but not the `request` object.

You may want to use custom request [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/).

Comment: Indeed middleware solved my problem, I used the already implemented session middleware to do it.